# Understanding iOS Subclassing

Tags: ios, uitableview, inheritance

I am currently working on building an application that contains a couple of  `UIViewController`s with a `UITableView` in each. Each table view will contain a custom cell that I have created as a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

Since the two view controllers will be very much similar in appearance and functionality, I created a base class of `UITableView` for the others to inherit the shared properties and methods from.

However, I am unsure of how to structure the delegate and data source methods within each. For example, I want the custom cells to have actions that are available when the user swipes from right-to-left, and I would like the cells in both view controllers to have the same actions. My code for adding the actions to the custom table view cells is currently being implemented in each of the view controllers:

```
// Enable the default swipe-to-delete functionality of the cells
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

    var likeAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Like") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
        println("Beer added to \"Like\"")
        // Save the beer into the "Like" group
        tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)

    }

    var tryAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Try") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
        println("Beer added to \"Try\"")
        // Save the beer into the "Try" group
        tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    }

    var dislikeAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Dislike") { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
        println("Beer added to \"Dislike\"")
        // Save the beer into the "Dislike" group
        tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    }

    likeAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.26, green: 0.74, blue: 0.69, alpha: 1)
    tryAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.25, blue: 0.29, alpha: 1)
    dislikeAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.74, green: 0.38, blue: 0.33, alpha: 1)

    return [dislikeAction, tryAction, likeAction]
}
```

Since I want these actions to be added to both table views in my view controllers, can I implement this method in the base class and let the two subclassed view controllers' table views inherit this? Or do I need to implement this method in each view controller that I want to give its cells the functionality?

I am a little confused on how to go about reusing these kind of methods that belong to a table view when the table views that I want to share features are in different view controllers.

**EDIT 1**:

The base class also conforms to the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol so that the other view controllers can inherit the delegate methods since their functionality will be the same. If something needs a little different behavior, then I can override the method.

**EDIT 2 - SOLVED**:

I ended up figuring out what I was trying to accomplish. I had to implement this in my base class, which enabled the swipe gesture to present the action buttons in my custom table view cells:

```
// Enable the default swipe-to-delete functionality of the cells
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
```

Comment: You should never subclass UITableView.

Comment: @Neal So how do I prevent myself from having to repeat that same implementation of code in multiple view controllers?

Comment: The delegate and dataSource of the UITableView should handle all the functionality. Generally, your UIViewController is both. You may want to make a base class of your view controller.

Comment: @Neal The base class that I created subclasses `UIViewController`. The two `UIViewController`s inherit from that base class. The two `UIViewController`s that are inheriting from the base class each have a `UITableView` in them.

Comment: why subclassing UITableview and not UITableViewController?